# Byte array manipulation in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, bit-manipulation

I've tried hours to figure out how to manipulate a byte array to do the "unpacking" and packing with C#.

> **Packed Data Format**
>
> Data is packed in 8 byte “packets”, with the MS bit stripped from 7
>   parameter bytes, and packed into an eighth byte, which is sent at the start
>   of the 8 byte packet.
>
> *Example:*
>
> ```
> Input Data 
> 1 A7 A6 A5 A4 A3 A2 A1 A0
> 2 B7 B6 B5 B4 B3 B2 B1 B0 
> 3 C7 C6 C5 C4 C3 C2 C1 C0 
> 4 D7 D6 D5 D4 D3 D2 D1 D0 
> 5 E7 E6 E5 E4 E3 E2 E1 E0 
> 6 F7 F6 F5 F4 F3 F2 F1 F0 
> 7 G7 G6 G5 G4 G3 G2 G1 G0 
>
> Packed MIDI data
> 1 00 G7 F7 E7 D7 C7 B7 A7
> 2 00 A6 A5 A4 A3 A2 A1 A0
> 3 00 B6 B5 B4 B3 B2 B1 B0
> 4 00 C6 C5 C4 C3 C2 C1 C0
> 5 00 D6 D5 D4 D3 D2 D1 D0
> 6 00 E6 E5 E4 E3 E2 E1 E0
> 7 00 F6 F5 F4 F3 F2 F1 F0
> 8 00 G6 G5 G4 G3 G2 G1 G0
> ```

Each row indicates one byte, each column one bit (MSB first).

How do I implement this conversion?

Comment: I feel like your question stopped half way...

Comment: The specification and examples come from http://www.scribd.com/doc/54261730/Prophet-08-Manual-v1-3#page=60 and doesn't seem to provide any additional detail than what's in the question. So I guess it needs some ingenuity to figure out how to implement this conversion.

Comment: I think i understand: The rows indicate one byte, each position in the row one bit. The letter in the values is actually the number/position of the byte in the unpacked sequence (sort of), with A=1st byte, B=2nd byte, etc... The number after the letter is the actual bit in the byte at the position the number indicated. That is my guess, i don't know for sure, hence no answer.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the spec right, this should do the trick:

```
byte[] input = new byte[7] { 0x81, 0x82, 0x03, 0x84, 0x05, 0x06, 0x87 };

byte[] output = new byte[8];

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    output[0] |= (byte)((input[i] >> 7) << i);
    output[i + 1] = (byte)(input[i] & 0x7F);
}

// output == { 0x4b, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07 }

// output[0] == 0b01001011
```

As you can see, the most significant bit of each input byte in the example is cleared, and a prefix byte is added with the most significant bit of each input byte.